# How to pause YouTube videos on Ubuntu with Chrome?

Tags: youtube, google-chrome

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 with Google Chrome.

I cannot pause YouTube videos with <kbd>spacebar</kbd> like I used to be able to and as I have read in different places. What happens is, that when I press <kbd>spacebar</kbd>, the video continues but I see only a yellow square around the play button of the video.